# What is other option if I don’t want to use @Generated annotation in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS) 
@Column(name="create_date", insertable=false,updatable=false)

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options.

```
ALWAYS
Indicates the value is generated on insert and on update.
INSERT
Indicates the value is generated on insert.
NEVER
Indicates the value is never generated.
```

Answer (score 0):

## @Generated Annotation

**GenerationTime.ALWAYS**

> GenerationTime.ALWAYS updates the entity at both time insert and
>   update. In the case of GenerationTime.ALWAYS, the property should not
>   be insertable and updatable.

```
@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "modified_date", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private Date modifiedDate;
```

**GenerationTime.INSERT**

> GenerationTime.INSERT updates the entity only at time of insertion . In the case of GenerationTime.INSERT, the property should not
>   be insertable.

```
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "created_date", insertable = false) 
private Date createdDate;
```

**GenerationTime.NEVER**

> GenerationTime.NEVER does not update the entity neither on update nor insert time.

```
@Generated(GenerationTime.NEVER)
```

---

## @CreationTimestamp @UpdateTimestamp

These annotations could also be used by each of the following types:

- java.time.LocalDate (since Hibernate 5.2.3)
- java.time.LocalDateTime (since Hibernate 5.2.3)
- java.util.Date
- java.util.Calendar
- java.sql.Date
- java.sql.Time
- java.sql.Timestamp

  ```
  @Column
  @CreationTimestamp
  private LocalDateTime createDateTime;

  @Column
  @UpdateTimestamp
  private LocalDateTime updateDateTime;
  ```